# Kill processes and programs in windows instantly

Tags: windows, console, cmd.exe, kill

Some programs I run can't be killed and terminated even from the Task Manager. Sometimes they can be terminated but it takes too long. I want a method that always kills them instantly. Is there any application or command for this?

*Edit:*
It takes too long to exit some programs, especially those which work with IO (`xcopy` etc). I want a way to kill them quickly. In Linux, when you kill a program it will be terminated quickly. Why can't I do it in Windows 7?

Comment: In Linux when you kill a program it will be terminated instantly.is there any such way in windows?

Comment: Perhaps someone could post a link to the reasoning given to discourage `kill -9` type program exits?  You're not giving the program a chance to exit gracefully, risking corruption, left over files, blood, gore, just messy.  "Takes too long"?  You're in that much of a hurry? Wow.

Comment: @lornix , No I'm not very hurry.it takes too long only for some programs, specially programs which work with IO.

Answer (score 6):

Introducing the **taskkill** command

syntax: 
**taskkill /f /im nameofApplication.exe**

or you can do it manually:

1. Start **Task Manager**
2. In the **Applications Tab** right click the running or not responding application and hit **Go to process**
3. You will be redirected to the process of the program, right click and hit **End Process Tree**
4. *The program will now forcibly quit*

Hope this helps!

Comment: it takes too long to exit some program. specially those which work with IO(xcopy,...). I want a way to kill it quickly.

Comment: You have to be patient, sometimes the specs of your machine also affects the time needed to completely remove the process and the type of process you'd like to kill. I am also a linux user and I agree with you that killing a process is really easy but you have to accept the fact the windows is different.

Answer (score 1):

You could use help from [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/), you can suspend, terminate, and end process trees in almost instantaneously.